# How to trigger an Airflow DAG via API using curl

Tags: curl, airflow, airflow-api

I'm currently able to use the API on a standalone instance of Airflow, and I get a successful response when getting a DAG description with:

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/my_dag' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --user "admin:thepassword"
```

The problem is when I try to trigger the same dag using:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/my_dag/dagRuns' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --user "admin:the_password"
```

That returns this response:

```
{
  "detail": "None is not of type 'object'",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/BadRequest"
}
```

I suppose my curl call is wrong, but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not providing a payload/body in your request. You can do this with the `-d` flag.

[API reference.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run)

Example: `curl -X POST 'localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/my_dag/dagRuns' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --user "admin:the_password" -d '{"conf": {}}'`

Comment: Thanks for the collaboration but, if you're going to post an answer, you shall add an example instead of a sole link to a documentation.

Comment: Updated with example request from the question.

Comment: That's great, but in my case this was enough: `curl -X POST 'localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/my_dag/dagRuns' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --user "admin:the_password" -d '{}'`, but your answer was what I needed, thanks